# DropWizard fails to serialize JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, dropwizard

Even a message like this fails:

```
{
    "message": "Hi!"
}
```

with this server-side error:

```
! java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:1243) ~[test-jar.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:567) ~[test-jar.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:484) ~[test-jar.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425) ~[test-jar.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383) ~[test-jar.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336) ~[test-jar.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223) ~[test-jar.jar:na]
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.NonblockingServletHolder.handle(NonblockingServletHolder.java:49) ~[test-jar.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669) ~[test-jar.jar:na]
! at io.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:29) ~[test-jar.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[test-jar.jar:na]
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.handle(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:43) ~[test-jar.jar:na]
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.doFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:38) ~[test-jar.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[test-jar.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) [test-jar.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) [test-jar.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [test-jar.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) [test-jar.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [test-jar.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [test-jar.jar:na]
```

This is the method that's failing:

```
@GET
@Path("/test/{id}")
public Response test(@PathParam("id")
                                  String id, @QueryParam("alt")
                                  String alternativeSerializationFormat) {
    Response getEntityResponse;

    String message  = "{\"message:\": \"Hi!!!\"}";
    getEntityResponse = Response.ok().entity(message).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE+"; charset=UTF-8").build();
    return getEntityResponse;
}
```

I'm thinking that it might be a classpath issue. Does anyone have a recommendation on what could be causing this? We use Avro which forces us to have Jackson 1 on our classpath as well as Jackson 2.

Comment: Can you try remove header() call? It looks like problem with header.

Comment: I created a little main method with your exact code and I have no issues. I am using jackson 2 though. Is your stacktrace complete?